# How to connect html in folder with php

Tags: php

Im trying to connect 
php file from folder :
"localhost" to "localhost/folder"
but it always says: "Object not found!"

```
<a href='file://localhost/folder/narudzba.html'></a>
```

What do i have to change??

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href='/folder/narudzba.html'></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using a `Localhost` server. In that case you should use the protocol `http` instead of `file`. Therefore, your link should look like this:

```
<a href='http://localhost/folder/narudzba.html'></a>
```

Or like **@paranoid** said, like below if you would like to use relative paths, which is normally a better solution:

```
<a href='/folder/narudzba.html'></a>
```

**Edit:** As you are not using the default server port 80, try this solution:

```
<a href='http://localhost:82/folder/narudzba.html'></a>
```

Comment: None of this works
it still says "Object not found!"
maybe it has something to do with port. My port is 82 not 80 (so i always have to enter http://localhost:82/...)???